# Alternative ways for selecting value from drop down list in selenium using java

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have got an error with select the value from drop down list in selenium using java.

```
//Select the Warehouse
Select Warehouse= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpath.warehouse_SVR)));
System.out.println("Element is identified ");
Warehouse.selectByValue("3");
System.out.println("Value is selected");
Thread.sleep(1000);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
```

I used the methods which are related to select the value from drop down list. Here I mentioned the .selectByValue() method. Even though I used .selectByIndex() or .selectByVisibleText() methods, still  I have got the error. What is the possible way to select the value from drop down list?

This is the Html code for that particular drop down list.

```
<select id="ctl00_cphbody_rptRNDViewer_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue" class="aspNetDisabled" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; width: 217px;" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphbody$rptRNDViewer$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$cphbody$rptRNDViewer$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue">
<option value="1">- All -</option>
<option value="2">Damage Warehouse-1000003061</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Primary Warehouse-1000003061</option>
<option value="4">VAN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Command duration or timeout: 5.99 seconds

Comment: @RosiniyaRobertStanley Can you please provide HTML code for that drop down?

Comment: Add StackTrace and all the steps needed to reproduce the issue in the question itself [edit] . Also go through [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Check out following 
Use implcit wait before, Warehouse.selectByValue("3");

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try following updated code :

```
Select Warehouse= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xpath.warehouse_SVR)));
System.out.println("Element is identified ");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(Warehouse)); 
Warehouse.selectByValue("3");
System.out.println("Value is selected");
Thread.sleep(1000);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: According to your answer, I created the 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

Anyhow, I cannot move further more. When I type the 
wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(Warehouse));

 I get message as “Cannot resolve the method ‘presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select)’ ”.

Comment: @RosiniyaRobertStanley, this is because you need to use `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` instead of just `presenceOfElementLocated`

Answer (score 0):

```
  public boolean selectValueFromDropDown(String searchValue) {      

  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphbody_rptRNDViewer_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue"));     
  element.click();
  element.sendKeys(searchValue);
  element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  return true;
    }
```

Comment: what should I insert for searchValue?

Comment: specific value of dropdown list which you want to find or click

Comment: I inserted that value.In my case, I have to get the value Primary Warehouse-1000003061

Comment: I still have an error when I insert the String value