# Values from list not match with my string

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select one auto complete dropdown from the below code for unites states but below issues are observed.

1. I have asked to select value="United States" but its selects Albania
2. It throws stale element exception.

I am not able to understand whats happening.

```
void selectFromDropdown(WebElement webName, String valtoSelect){
        WebElement dropdown = webName;
        dropdown.click(); // assuming you have to click the "dropdown" to open it
        List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            for (WebElement option : options)
            {
                if (option.getText().equals(valtoSelect))
                {
                    option.click(); // click the desired option
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

[image]

```
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="disable-clearable" placeholder="Country of Registration" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="">
```

The problem I see is for open that auto drop down I am clicking on this element "`//*[@id='disable-clearable']` "and then checking ul "`//ul[@role='listbox']`"

Comment: you can select the option directly using xpath `dropdown.findElement(By.Xpath("//option[.='" + valtoSelect + "']").click()`. If that doesn't work, please share the html of the listbox.

Comment: are you sure it is select element?

Comment: remove break and write it after  option.click() method.

Comment: I tried doing it with dropdown.findElement(By.Xpath("//option[.='" + valtoSelect + "']").click(), didnt work. The problem I see is for open that auto drop down I am click ing on this element "//*[@id='disable-clearable'] "and then checking ul "//ul[@role='listbox']"

Comment: @Sobhit Sharma try this one also you may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44519345/7689879

Comment: thanks Prashant. But I found work around.

Answer (score 1):

If the options are available in the HTML you can select an item from a dropdown by three ways:

```
@Test(testName = "select by tekst")
public void selectByVisibleTekst(){
    WebElement country= driver.findElement(By.xpath("locatorValue"));
    new Select(country).selectByVisibleText("tekstToSelect");
}

@Test(testName = "select by value")
public void selectByValue(){
    WebElement country= driver.findElement(By.xpath("locatorValue"));
    new Select(country).selectByValue("valueToSelect");
}

@Test(testName = "select by index")
public void selectByIndex(){
    WebElement country= driver.findElement(By.xpath("locatorValue"));
    new Select(country).selectByIndex(valueOfIndex);
}
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "ul"

Comment: I got the solution. Posted down there.

Comment: Ok nice to hear mate!

Answer (score 0):

After taking inputs from various friends here and did some reasearch and the below method worked for me.

```
public void selectCountry(){
        String valtoSelect = "United States";
        countryOfReg.click();
        List<WebElement> webMom = Collections.singletonList(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']")));
        for (int i = 0; i <= webMom.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='disable-clearable-option-"+i+"']")).getText());
            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='disable-clearable-option-"+i+"']")).getText().equals(valtoSelect)){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='disable-clearable-option-"+i+"']")).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If the dropdown is really a Selection box then the following code should work

```
void selectFromDropdown(WebElement webName, String valtoSelect){
    Select select = new Select(webName)));
    select.selectByVisibleText(valtoSelect);
    // or maybe select.selectByValue(valtoSelect); depending how you setup the dropdown
}
```

where Select is `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`

Comment: Encountered exception- org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "ul"

Comment: OK but then this means you haven't passed the `select` element to the method. Maybe take a look at the DOM and find the `select` element and pass that in? I think you might be passing the dropdown menu itself maybe try passing the item you clicked to open the dropdown?

Comment: I checked DOM and there was no select element it self. all they did with ul and li.